# Number of coins to get 2 Heads with probability 0.5

Tags: probability

I'm actually stuck on what seems like a fairly simple problem. How many coins do you have to toss to get exactly 2 Heads in total with a probability of 0.5?

I realize that it is 3 coins, because I can write it out and see that, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this question? I know we can use a Normal Approximation as the number of Heads we are looking to get becomes relatively large, however, I am unable to think of a method for only getting few Heads.

Thank You

Comment: "I know we can use a Normal Approximation as the number of Heads we are looking to get becomes relatively large" *Relatively large*, such as: **3**??

Comment: @Did Yes. I guess my issue is I don't know for what number of Heads its actually okay to apply the Normal Approximation.

Comment: @BarryCipra It is exactly 2 Heads.

Comment: It's not possible to get exactly 2 heads with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. The highest probability that can be achieved is $\frac{3}{8}$ for both $n=3$ and $n=4$. You can see this by maximising $g(n)=\binom{n}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^n$ over integers $n\ge2$, and noting that the function $g$ is decreasing for $n\ge4$.

Comment: The probability of getting *exactly* 2 heads with 3 coins is $3/8$. Do you mean *at least* 2 heads?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I apologize. My second statement is wrong and I've deleted it.

Comment: @Marconius Thank You. I guess this question isn't correct or is in fact a trick question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the wonders of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)? It's essentially a tool for computing the probability of $k$ successes (heads in your case, so $k = 2$) in $n$ trials (total coin tosses) when each trial is independent of each other and $p$ which is the probability of success for a single trial. ($p = 0.5$ in this case).

With $p$ and $k$ known, you're left with the following equation:

$\binom{n}{2} \times 0.5^2 \times 0.5^{n-2} = 0.5$. Solve for $n$.

Comment: See Barry's comment

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, can't see it, has probably been removed already

Comment: @kviiri I am aware of this. But it is not solvable by hand, which is what I need to be able to do.